# how to update only one object field in nodejs mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i'm going to change only book_mode field of role and book_mode field of status, but after findOneAndUpdate() executed, patrol_mode field of role and status disappeared. I want to preserve that field. How can i do?

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
user_id: String,
name: String,
avatar: String,
role: {
    book_mode: Number,
    patrol_mode: Number
},
status: {
    book_mode: Number,
    patrol_mode: Number
},
created_at: Number,
updated_at: Number
}, {collection: 'users'});

var updateData = {
status: {
    book_mode: APPROVED
},
role: {
    book_mode: req.body.role
}
}

User.findOneAndUpdate({
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body._id)
        },
        {$set: updateData},
        function(err, doc){
            if(err){
                resData.message = 'failed';
                resData.code = 501;
                resData.flag = false;
                resData.data = err;
                res.send(resData);
                return;
            }
            resData.data = doc;
            resData.message = 'success';
            resData.code = 200;
            resData.flag = true
            res.send(resData);
            return;
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are re assigning the whole parent objects to contain only book_mood instead you can use the dot notation to access an specific field.

```
updateData = {
  "status.book_mode":  APPROVED,
  "role.book_mode":  req.body.rol
  }
```

That's if APPROVED and req.body.rol holds strings for book_mood, if it contains an object so you have to change it to be

```
updateData = {
  "status.book_mode":  APPROVED.book_mode,
  "role.book_mode":  req.body.rol.book_mode
  }
```

Comment: thank you very much. you've helped me twice over 1 day. you're my god.